# Android Edit Text with Validation is not working?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I'm new to Android and making and app which required Edit Text and it's validation. I have tried different ways to validate the edit text but is is not working.

I want to set the range of value to be entered for eg: between 13 to 80 if it's exceed then gives error, my code gives error only when the edit text is empty but not when value is less than 13 or greater than 80.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
EditText age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
EditText weight= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
EditText height= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);

Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal);

calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             final String a=age.getText().toString();
             final String w=weight.getText().toString();
             final String h=height.getText().toString();

             if(a.length()==0 || (a.length()<12 && a.length()>81)){
                 age.requestFocus();
                 age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
             }

             else if(w.length()==0 || (w.length()<40 && w.length()>301)){
                 weight.requestFocus();
                 weight.setError("Weight required!");
             }
             else if(h.length()==0 || (h.length()<49 && h.length()>251)){
                 height.requestFocus();
                 height.setError("Height required!");
             }

         else{

             aN=Integer.parseInt(a);

             wN=Integer.parseInt(w);

             hN=Integer.parseInt(h);

             }
         } 
         });
```

Comment: a.length()<12 && a.length()>81 this is wrong. first convert that a to interger and compare with 12

Comment: You should compare value of edittext instead of length of editext see  below answer.

Comment: no...its again giving error....i had just edited my question with full code may be this will help you to understand the question properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
a.length()<12 && a.length()>81)
```

This line means "length is less than 12 AND at the same time it is greater than 81". It will always be false.

It should be

```
int ageValue = Integer.valueOf(a);
if (ageValue < 12 || ageValue > 80) {
```

And there is no need to check for `length() == 0`, because it falls in `length() < 12` condition.

Comment: Additionally,as a rule of thumb its better to prevent invalid values from being typed than validating them. Use android:maxLength="80" in your edittext layout.

Comment: Here a is age and it is a String, how come you are comparing a.length() ??  @Zohaib you should not compare with a.length(). first convert into int and then compare , see my post http://stackoverflow.com/a/24677563/2194456

Comment: now this code giving error to all values whether it is 0 ,<12 ,>80 or any valid value.

Comment: no...its again giving error....i had just edited my question with full code may be this will help you to understand the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer.parse()`, for example:

```
int a = Integer.parse(edittext1.getText().toString().trim());

if(a >= 13 && a <= 80)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: no...its again giving error....i had just edited my question with full code may be this will help you to understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here a is age and it is a String, how come you are comparing a.length() ??

Actual could should be

```
int intAge = 0; 
 try{
 intAge = Integer.parseInt(a);
 }catch(Exception e){
 }
  if (a.length()==0 || (intAge < 12 || intAge > 80)) {
// your code  
}
```

And then compare  for other cases

Comment: no...its again giving error....i had just edited my question with full code may be this will help you to understand the question properly.

Comment: "unfortunately app has stopped error"...please review my question once more as i had just edited it with full code.

Comment: please post the logcat, and i guess "have you initilized radiogendergroup" ?

Comment: logcat error: Value No of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: from where Json object came from ? i have not seen json in your code !

Comment: could you post full class file

Answer (score 0):

```
     if(age.getText().toString().length()==0 || 
                              !(a>12 && a<=80))
                 {
                     age.requestFocus();
                     age.setError("Between 13 ans 80");
                 }

                 else if(weight.getText().toString().length()==0 || 
                                                 !(w>40 && w<=300))
                 {
                     weight.requestFocus();
                     weight.setError("Weight required!");
                 }
                 else if(height.getText().toString().length()==0 || 
                                                 !(h>50 && h<=250))
                 {
                     height.requestFocus();
                     height.setError("Height required!");
                 }
```

Comment: no...its again giving error....i had just edited my question with full code may be this will help you to understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you basic code for your requirement so you can extend it for your purpose. Use below code

MainActivity.java

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int age = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
            if (age > 13 && age <= 80) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Valid age", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

This code will toast a message of'Valid age' if you enter age between 13 & 80.